# Not able to fit img to div size : CSS Grid

Tags: html, css

Hey I am trying to fit `img` to its `div` container. I am using CSS Grid for the layout.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row: auto;
}

.item {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.banner {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}


/* laptops and desktops */

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-row: 1fr;
    padding: 60px 130px 20px 130px;
    grid-gap: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="banner" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479936343636-73cdc5aae0c3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6672a25aa653266572aaf2be253fb56a&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="banner" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508296695146-257a814070b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=bfacf656c686ff7e39ac1386691557be&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" />
  </div>
</div>
```

There's always a white space at the bottom of the `item` container. The image is covering the whole container. Can someone please tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: _"There's always a white space at the bottom of the item container"_ - it doesn't seem to be?

Comment: Open full page, You can see the white space at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help you:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row: auto;
}

.item {
    /*height: 500px;*/
    max-width: 500px; /*Remove this line if 500px limit is not important for you.  */
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.banner {
  /*max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  display: block;

}


/* laptops and desktops */

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-row: 1fr;
    padding: 60px 130px 20px 130px;
    grid-gap: 50px;

  }

  
}
```

```html
    <body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="banner" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479936343636-73cdc5aae0c3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6672a25aa653266572aaf2be253fb56a&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="banner" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508296695146-257a814070b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=bfacf656c686ff7e39ac1386691557be&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" />
  </div>
</div>
                     
        
    </body>
```

Comment: The white space is still there

Comment: Really? The bottom white space between images and black border? I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

although your media query is strange, I think you want to fix ratio problem, so I try like this:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row: auto;
}
.item{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.ratio-1-1{
  padding-top: calc(100% - 2px);
  /* 2px = border * 2 */
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0;
}
.ratio-1-1 img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1025px){
  .container {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-row: 1fr;
      padding: 60px 130px 20px 130px;
      grid-gap: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="ratio-1-1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479936343636-73cdc5aae0c3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6672a25aa653266572aaf2be253fb56a&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="ratio-1-1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508296695146-257a814070b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=bfacf656c686ff7e39ac1386691557be&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your image is 500x500, so the padding-top on .ratio-1-1 is image height/image width * 100% .

Answer (score -1):

To your .banner class add

```
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
```

This will stretch your image and will not lose ratio at all.

Comment: I forgot to check it on small screen. Try this code:

`.banner {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}`